# Differentiability of Fourier Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, fourier-series

The following Fourier Series is continuous (by M-test)
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin{n^n x}}{n^n}}$$

Is it differentiable anywhere, and if so where?

http://kryakin.org/at/hardy_1916_W.pdf covers similar things, but I didn't really understand it.

Answer (score 4):

This is the sort of thing I knew something about years ago. I'm not sure of the answer to your question, but I can say that the series you give is right on the borderline.

Consider $f=\sum a_n\sin(n^n t)$. If $n^n a_n\to0$ (and the $a_n$ are real) then $f$ is in the little-oh Zygmund class, and hence is differentiable on a dense set. On the other hand if $n^na_n\to\infty$ then it's  not hard to show that $f$ is nowhere differentiable. Your function is just exactly between those two classes. Possibly I'm being stupid again, or possibly it's not that easy to determine whether it's differentiable at at least one point.

**Edit** Rusty. Thinking about it a little more, I believe the function is nowhere differentiable; proving it would take a little space. What's unclear is whether it satisfies a $Lip_1$ condition at some point.

Comment: so it the bottom were (n^(n+1)) instead it would be differentiable in a dense set? do you know if it would be differentiable everywhere if I replace the bottom with (n^(n+1))?

Comment: If you put $n^{(n+1)}$ in the denominator then formal differentiation would give a Fourier series wiith coefficients $1/n$. Since $\sum 1/n^2$ is finite, that means the function would be differentiable "in $L^2$", and hence would be diifferentiable almost everywhere. With $n^{(n+1+\epsilon)}$ it would be continuously differentiable. Just $n^{(n+\epsilon)}$ would be enough to make it differentiable on a dense set.

Comment: Btw this is all understood much better than it was in 1916. Look around for material on "lacunary series"...